# Different Versions of SCCM 2007 Clients Installed Throughout the Environment

Tags: sccm, sccm-2007

I want to know why is it that I see multiple SCCM 2007 client versions installed throughout my environment rather than just one?

I upgraded my SCCM 2007 server last year to R3 and most of my systems, about 3400 of them, show the right version (4.00.6487.2157). But when I run a report I see that about 900 still have the Service Pack 2 version (4.00.6486.2000) and even 34 have the KB977384 version (4.00.6487.2188). I don't really get it. Where can I look on the client itself to pull the actual client version info. I looked in the "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\SMS\Mobile Client\Product Version" value but even on systems where my report shows the 4.00.6487.2157 version is installed, this Registry value still shows 4.00.6486.2000.

We are in the middle of upgrading to SCCM 2012 and I was asked this question by management regarding the differing SCCM 2007 client versions.

Can someone please help me make sense of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the workstation's sccm client software is busted, then the client won't update, and even if it did update, if the client is somehow corrupt then it won't report back and you're dealing with old data.

What works for us is to deploy a login script via group policy that checks the version of sccm  that installed, and update it if it doesn't match the desired version. It also checks for wmi corruption and different things, but I'm sure you get the point.

There's a lot more to it (tons of moving parts in sccm), and I don't understand all of it but I do know that much. Microsoft also has some technet pages with best practices for deploying the sccm client, you could look into that.

Comment: I use GPO SCCM client push as well as automatic client push.

Comment: I dont know why I mentioned client push here. I must have been reading something else. Anyway, this sounds great man. Thanks